# Запятая между причастным оборотом и придаточным

Tags: запятые, синтаксис, сложное-предложение, однородные-члены

Как правильно, совы? Я думаю, вариант 1-й правильный.

1. Я позвоню своему братцу, знающему хорошо-таки информатику и который может, я уверен, мне помочь.
2. Я позвоню своему братцу, знающему хорошо-таки информатику, и который может, я уверен, мне помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Сочетание "который может" обычно заменяет причастие "могу́щий".
И думаю, что в определенном контексте все-таки возможна однородность (если сделать акцент на местоимении "своему").

Получаем (без запятой, с упрощением):
*Я позвоню **своему** братцу, хорошо знающему информатику и который может мне помочь.*

Да и "такой", собственно, вроде можно подставить (если у говорящего несколько братьев или имеются в виду друзья — братцы):
*Я **позвоню** такому братцу...*

•• Нашла в Нацкорпусе **примеры** с похожим (однородным) использованием определительного оборота и придаточного предложения (понимаю — давнишние, но ведь есть же!):

*При этом я советовал бы употребить в дело такт, **врожденный каждому и который может** становиться все быстрее и быстрее* (К. Д. Ушинский. Воскресные школы (1861));

*Европейский рассказ (немецкий), тоже XIII в., **немногим**, по-видимому, **более молодой**, чем фабло, **и который может** равно восходить и к фабло, и к Жаку де Витри...* (С. Ф. Ольденбург. Восточное влияние на средневековую повествовательную литературу Запада (1934));

*Он очень милый человек (говорили Кочетков и его жена), влиятельный; **настоящий художник и который может мне помочь** конкретными советами, куда обратиться мне и что дальше делать* (Г. С. Эфрон. Дневники. Т. 1. 1940 (1940)).

Согласна, не стандартное предложение.

Comment: У меня вопрос по поводу указательного слова "такой". У автора может быть несколько своих братьев, знающих информатику, и он выбирает того, кто не откажется помочь? Вы это имели в виду? И пожалуйста, укажите, на какие грамматические источники ориентирован ваш ответ? Если только на давнишние примеры, то этого недостаточно. Ведь грамматика может меняться, достаточно вспомнить тему деепричастных оборотов.

Answer (score 3):

Второй ответ (делаю **вывод по структуре** предложения)

*Я позвоню своему братцу, знающему хорошо-таки информатику и который может, я уверен, мне помочь.*

(1) *Я позвоню брату, **который** знает информатику и **который** может мне помочь.*

**Корректно.**

(2) *Я позвоню брату, знающ**ему** информатику  и котор**ый** может мне помочь.*

**Некорректно** (даже на слух).  Разные окончания: ***знающЕМУ, которЫЙ.***

(3) *Я позвоню брату, **знающему** информатику, **который** может мне помочь.*

Без союза И звучит лучше, но можно ли использовать такую **грамматику?** Это вопрос **к лингвистам**, также интересно найти примеры в современной **литературе.**

**[ОШИБКИ В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯХ С ОДНОРОДНЫМИ ЧЛЕНАМИ](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/784-34_predlozheniya_s_odnorodnymi_chlenami.html)**

В устной и письменной речи наблюдается много ошибок и недочётов, связанных с использованием однородных членов. Можно выделить несколько типов таких ошибок.

Не следует соединять **как однородные члены разнотипные синтаксические конструкции:**

(1) член предложения и придаточное предложение: Я не люблю войну и когда получаю двойку;

(2) **обособленное определение и определительное придаточное:**

*В жюри избрали Попова, **занявшего** первое место в турнире и **который** отличался спокойствием;*

(3) обособленное обстоятельство (в частности, деепричастный оборот) и обстоятельственное придаточное предложение: Когда гулял по городу и увидев несчастных детей, он задумал написать картину;

(4) обособленные обстоятельства и обособленные определения: Изменивший присяге и общаясь с Пугачёвым, Швабрин проявил себя как низкий человек.

Comment: См.ссылку на учебник.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написала так **(без союза И):**

*Я позвоню своему **братцу**, **знающему** хорошо-таки информатику,  **который** может, я уверен, мне помочь.*

1. Здесь после определяемого существительного стоит обособленный оборот, а далее  придаточное.

Я сомневаюсь в том, что в заданном предложении оборот может находиться в **однородных** отношениях с придаточным.

Здесь придаточное **распространительного** вида, а не определительного (нельзя использовать указательное слово "**такому** братцу"). Поэтому эти конструкции относятся к определяемому существительному **независимо**.

Как мне кажется, это **интересное** предложение.

2. **Другой вариант** предложения (с однородными сказуемыми):

*Я позвоню своему брату, который **знает** информатику **и может** мне **помочь**.*

Или (без *который*): *Я позвоню своему брату, **он** знает информатику и может мне помочь.*  Такой вариант ближе к разговорной речи.

Comment: Sharon, a вы считаете, что предложение построено верно? В одном предложении объединены причастие и придаточное.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Очень правильный вопрос, давайте обсудим нестандартную грамматику по грамматическим источникам, а не по примерам из прошлого века. В современной литературе этого нет, так что стоит задуматься.

Comment: Нет чего в современной литературе?

Comment: Нет такой модели:  существительное + причастный оборот и определительное придаточное, связанные союзом И. Но модель  без союза И тоже под вопросом, В грамматике описание таких конструкций мне не встречалось.  А вам?  Ну и по конкретному предложению тоже есть вопросы: это распространительное, а не определительное придаточное. Как его вообще можно связывать союзом И с определительным оборотом? И все молчат, никому до этого дела нет. Кому хочется с грамматикой возиться.

Comment: Есть модель, которая считается ошибочной. Причастный оборот нельзя соединять в однородный ряд с придаточным.

Comment: А в каком источнике это указано? Что же вы не дали ответ? Было бы очень кстати.

Comment: Если честно, лень писать.

Comment: Вечером постараюсь написать.

Comment: https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/784-34_predlozheniya_s_odnorodnymi_chlenami.html

Answer (score 1):

Ответ по комментарию

```
Sharon, a вы считаете, что предложение построено верно? В 
одном предложении объединены причастие и придаточное.
```

**Серж, конечно же нет, я так не считаю.** Я сразу хотела написать для него резолюцию:  предложение выглядит некорректно,  просто на слух. Потом убрала союз И, воде бы лучше стало.

1. Обратите внимание на примеры, с помощью которых решена эта задача: **прошлый и позапрошлый век, ни одного нового.** Устаревшая грамматика, но в современной разговорной речи встречается.

**Что плохо в примерах вообще,** так это то, что их "копируют", а это не всегда корректно: ***что верно там, неверно здесь.***

2. **[У  КУСТОВОЙ](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)** подробно описан этот **тип предложений** со всеми определениями, с полной классификацией(стр. 175-176, издание 2005 года).

*Таким образом, по указательному слову выделяется четыре группы ПАП с частными грамматическими значениями: первое, второе ГЗ — по **возможности — невозможности** употребления указательного слова (**выделительное и распространительное** ГЗ); третье, четвертое — по значению указательного слова (**собственно-выделительное и качественно-типизирующее**).*

*Союзные слова ***который*** или ***какой*** в составе СПП с ПАП обнаруживают свойства двух частей речи: **ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОГО** по формам рода и числа и **СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОГО** по форме
падежа. Форму рода и числа эти слова получают от опорного существительного, форма падежа зависит от их синтаксической
функции и связей с другими словами в придаточном.*

3. Сложновато? В новом издании дана более четкая классификация.  **Но что все это значит?**

*Вернулся **Петя**, который* (он, существительное) *весь день пробыл на озере.*  Нельзя сказать: **тот Петя**, который весь день пробыл на озере. Петя, вероятно, один.

Для **распространительных** предложений указательное слово невозможно. *Взошло солнце, **которое** осветило все вокруг.* У нас только одно солнце.

4. Но вот говорят: *Я позвоню (какому?) брату, знающему  информатику **и который** (= он) может мне помочь*.

У брата есть определение, то есть это известный брат, он выделен определением. Значит, придаточное **распространительное**: который (он). И вот мы это определение (прилагательное) соединяем с существительным ***который*** (он) и считаем их **однородными**. Корректно ли это? Как-то не очень. Но вот **соединяют** и примерами оправдывают...

5. Если **убрать союз И** и переставить определение, то все корректно: *Я позвоню знающему информатику брату, **который** (= он) может мне помочь.*

Можно ли использовать предложение **с обособленным оборотом?** Вот это вопрос, ответ на который надо искать в источниках.

**P.S.  Интересная особенность нашей «партитивной» речи.**

Составляем  два  корректных предложения/сообщения, а потом  в общем речевом потоке **соединяем** их союзом И по порядку следования:

(1) Я позвоню своему брату, знающему информатику.

(2) ...брату,  который может мне помочь.

Получилось: *Я позвоню своему брату, **знающему** информатику **и который** может мне помочь.*

То, что мы соединили несоединяемое, мы **не замечаем**. Но в **письменной** речи это выгляди как нечто неправильное, потому что в современной **литературе** этого нет.